# How to update this REGEX to make sure string does not have _(underscore) at the end or beigning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

This is the regular expression which i have, i need to make sure that string does not start or end with underscore , underscore may appear in between.

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+$/
```

I have tried

```
(?!_)
```

But doesn't seem to work

Allowed strings:

```
abcd
abcd_123
```

Not allowed strings:

```
abcd_
_abcd_123
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not too hard!

```
/^[^_].*[^_]$/
```

"Any character except an underscore at the start of the line (`^[^_]`), then any characters (`.*`), then any character except an underscore before the end of the line (`[^_]$`)."

This does require at least two characters to validate the string. If you want to allow one character lines:

```
/^[^_](.*[^_]|)$/
```

"Anything except an underscore to start the line, and then either some characters plus a non-underscore character before end-of-line, or just an immediate end-of-line.

Comment: Not too easy my friend! This would not validate input with length less than 2. Since the question does not specify the actual usage of this regex, we must take this into consideration as well.

Comment: Thanks .. I was looking for an expression that only allows these characters [a-zA-Z0-9_.-]

Comment: @nishant610 Just replace `.*` with `[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*` then.

Comment: Chris take a look at this [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/XbxgnWJZ3x).. that doesn't work with underscore in between the string

Comment: Sorry, just add the underscore to the allowed character class in the middle there. Character classes are nice because they're flexible! :D

Comment: Your rubular test text has newlines. The underscore is not the last character of that string, \n is.

Comment: Also, make sure the `-` is the last character of the class, or it'll be interpreted as a range indicator.

Answer (score 1):

You could approach this in the inverse way,

Check all those that do match starting and ending *underscores* like this:

```
/^_|_$/

^_         #starts with underscore
|          #OR
_$         #ends with underscore
```

And then eliminate those that match. The above regexp is much more easier to read.

Check : http://www.rubular.com/r/H3Axvol13b

Or you can try the longer regex:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9.-][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9.-]$|^[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+$|^[a-zA-Z0-9.-][a-zA-Z0-9.-]$/

^[a-zA-Z0-9.-]     #starts with a-z, or A-Z, or 0-9, or . -
[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*    #anything that can occur and the underscore
[a-zA-Z0-9.-]$     #ends with a-z, or A-Z, or 0-9, or . -
|                  #OR
^[a-zA-Z0-9.-]$    #for one-letter words
|                  #OR
^[a-zA-Z0-9.-][a-zA-Z0-9.-]$      #for two letter words
```

Check:  http://www.rubular.com/r/FdtCqW6haG

Answer (score 0):

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9.-][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+[a-zA-Z0-9.-]$/
```

Try this

**Description:**
In the first section, `[a-zA-Z0-9.-]`, regex only allows lower and upper case alphabets, digits, dot and hyphen.
In the next section, `[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+`, regex looks for a single or more than one characters that are lower or upper case alphabets, digits dot, hyphen or an underscore.
The last part, `[a-zA-Z0-9.-]`, is the same as the first part that restricts the input to end with an underscore.

Comment: this would not validate inputs of length less than 3

Comment: Is there any way to make this more readable and easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Recently had the same concern and this is how I did it.

```
// '"^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*$"' → Alphanumeric and 「.」「_」「-」
// "^[^_].*[^_]$" → Reject start and end of string if contains 「_」
// (?=) REGEX AND operator
SLUG_REGEX = '"(?=^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*$)(?=^[^_].*[^_]$)"';
```

I used this snippet for my Laravel Validation so you may need to change the code as needed like `"` to `/` based on your code sample and other answers' code.